Langchain pydantic schema args_schema ignored
I am trying to use a provided LangChain tool GmailGetThread and the key part of the code is
class GetThreadSchema(BaseModel):
    """Input for GetMessageTool."""

    thread_id: str = Field(
        ...,
        description="The thread ID.",
    )


class GmailGetThread(GmailBaseTool):
    """Tool that gets a thread by ID from Gmail."""

    name: str = "get_gmail_thread"
    description: str = (
        "Use this tool to search for email messages."
        " The input must be a valid Gmail query."
        " The output is a JSON list of messages."
    )
    args_schema: Type[GetThreadSchema] = GetThreadSchema

however it seems to ignore the schema and keeps trying to invoke the tool with the wrong field query or id instead of thread_id, for example
{
  "query": "thread:19026dfdc7e27431"
}

Why is the pydantic schema being ignored? thanks

Could you please show how do you invoke GmailGetThread tool? The problem might be related to the incorrect invocation.
